# APIs/Libraries/SDKs for handwriting tracking?

Tags: computer-vision, augmented-reality, handwriting-recognition

I'm trying to make a mobile AR application. I want to track the user's handwriting in real time using smartphones while the user writes on paper. That is to track every stroke made by the user.

I know some SDKs and products like ManoMotion and Leap Motion provide relatively precise hand tracking and analysis, but since writing on paper doesn't involve many motions and gestures, I don't think they are suitable.

I have searched online and haven't found any resources for my particular use case. So I would like to ask if there are other resources I should take a look at, or I should rely on some lower level APIs like OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

mhc, kind of late to answer this. But regarding ManoMotion you need to apply for access to the SDK products through the official website at www.manomotion.com the approval process is manual and they require some information regarding the intention of use in a project so I highly suggest to provide with as much detail as possible.